# Is there a way to use the IMPORTXML function of Google Sheets to import two queries at once?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I'm working on a tool to associate information about certain US Congressional Districts to their respective Members of Congress. To facilitate updating information about which Representatives serve which districts, I have opted to use an `IMPORTXML` function to retrieve up-to-date lists of Members and districts.

Fortunately, the US House Clerk publishes an [up-to-date xml file](http://clerk.house.gov/xml/lists/MemberData.xml) containing all the information I need. While I'm still trying to master xpath queries in Sheets, I think I've got a pretty basic handle on how to apply it for this project. I've found I can use the following function to retrieve State and Congressional District information:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://clerk.house.gov/xml/lists/MemberData.xml","//member/statedistrict")
```

And this is the data the function returns:

[image: here's a link because I'm not allowed to embed images yet]

Obviously, the results continues on for all 435 districts (actually 441 because it includes non-voting delegates too), and I can work with this. The issues I'm running into are when I try to import names of Members of the House with the following function:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://clerk.house.gov/xml/lists/MemberData.xml","//member/member-info/namelist")
```

And this is what that function returns:

[image: again, link because I can't embed yet]

And again, the results continue and include every Member. BUT, there are not 435  Members (441 including delegates) in the House right now due to some vacancies. And the `IMPORTXML` function that retrieves the names of the Members is only returning the 438 names it can find.

This means I cannot easily associate a Member to a district by simply using two `IMPORTXML` calls in two adjacent columns (one with the state/district, the other with names), as the lists don't line up, which can be seen at the bottom of the columns:

[image: here you can see the bottom of the columns]

I did a bit of digging, and learned that I can use two xpath queries in one `IMPORTXML`call by adding `|` between queries. Doing so with the xpath queries from the previous functions, the `IMPORTXML` call looks like this:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://clerk.house.gov/xml/lists/MemberData.xml","//member/statedistrict | //member/member-info/namelist")
```

And it returns a single column with the state/district interlaced with the names like this:

[image: here's a link to the image of the double query]

Interestingly though, when I do this, the names are appropriately paired with their districts; when there is a vacancy, the function imports the district, skips the non-existent name, imports the next district, and then the next name. So when it comes to a vacant district, this is what the output looks like (with the vacant districts highlighted):

[image: in this image, you can see the skipping of names]

However, for this to be useful, I really need to have this data in two columns, one with the state/district data, and the other with that district's respective Member's name. I'm trying to learn as much as I can about the problem, but this is just way beyond the scope of anything I've attempted in the past, and well-outside my comfort zone. That's where I stand so far, and any help at this point would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think after sleeping on it, I came up with a working solution (it's a touch inelegant, but it'll get the job done).

So using the `IMPORTXML` call with two queries gives the right order, but not the right spacing. What we can do in another column is check if the last two characters of the strings in each cell can be coerced into a number. If they can, then this value must be a State/District, and we will return that value. Here's the formula I used:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(E3:E,2))),E3:E,""))
```

Then in the next column over, we do the same thing, except we return the cells which didn't pass the test in the first column. But the trick here was that I actually had to offset this formula one row up, because this way it will return names on the same lines as their districts. Here's the formula I used for that:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(E3:E,2))),"",E3:E))
```

Here you can see it worked; the names line up, and there are blanks where there are vacancies:

[image: link to image because I can't embed yet]

And then to eliminate all the extra rows between entries, we can just filter them like this:

```
=FILTER(F3:G,F3:F<>"")
```

And what we're left with is two columns, one with state/district data, the other with the corresponding Representative's name:

[image]

Just wanted to update with what I've found in case someone else is struggling similarly.